# Crystal report returns wrong total with report groups (Double the original amount)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a report format like

```
Main Report

Installment # 1

SubReport
---------------
     Group 1 (Suppressed)
        Group 2 Detail 1: 
          ID    Amount (Formula field)
          --   ------- 
           1     100


         Group 2 (Footer)
          ------------
          Total  200
          ------------

         Group 2 Detail 2: 
          ID    Amount (Formula field)
          --   ------- 
           1     300


         Group 2 (Footer)
          ------------
          Total  600
          ------------
```

Problem I am having is that I am having wrong totals for the formula field in my Group 2 footer (I cannot understand why they are doubled)

I am creating the total field in 2 steps. First I create the variable inside the detail section of Group 2

**My formula field for the Amount**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

EvaluateAfter({@Share_Hundred_Percent});
EvaluateAfter({@Less_Commission});
EvaluateAfter({@Payment_NICL});
EvaluateAfter({@Payment_PRCL});

shared numberVar sumNetPayable;
numberVar result:=0;

if({Command.GENCLIENTCODE}=990) then
    result:= {@Share_Hundred_Percent}-{@Less_Commission} + {@Payment_PRCL}
else
    result:= {@Share_Hundred_Percent} - {@Less_Commission} ;

sumNetPayable := sumNetPayable + result;
result
```

Then I reset the total field in group 2 footer (but it prints double the amount)

**My formula field to display the total**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
EvaluateAfter({@Net_Payable});

shared numberVar sumNetPayable;
numberVar result:= sumNetPayable;
sumNetPayable :=0;

result
```

**Update**

@SilentD. Here is what I found. I deleted both the formulas from the report design view (detail formula+summary). I only placed the Sum Fomula in footer and it works. But when I put the details formula in report the totals are doubled

Comment: If the results are doubled then the formula must be executing twice per record.  Are there any other formulas that are referencing sumNetPayable?  Or do you have your amount formula placed twice in the report?

Comment: @SilentD nice comment, updated my post with new findings.

Comment: Sum ({"Amount (Formula field)"},{"based on which field in group"})..This works for me in general, you can customize it. Do check formula if it not having weird logic hidden. :)

Comment: Are you resetting the formula in group 2 header?

Comment: I don't understand the use of `
sumNetPayable := sumNetPayable + result;`

Comment: @Siva I am using the formula to calculate a sum of formula fields of totals (This I need to display in the footer). I am resetting the variable for summary in group 2 footer.

Comment: In `Amount` formula use  `sumNetPayable := result` instead of  `sumNetPayable := sumNetPayable + result`

Comment: @Siva that I have used to calculate grand total for formula field.

Comment: I guess you may have 2 details so when you are using that formula that is calculating 2 times so that is the reason I have asked you to try by removing that..

Comment: @Siva I found the problem! Actually, if you see in my footer formula, I have EvaluateAfter({@Net_Payable});. I removed it and all works fine. Cannot understand why it was doubling the figures.

Comment: I am glad you have solved your problem...

Comment: @Siva not without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end what fixed my problem was to remove the `EvaluateAfter({@Net_Payable});` from my formula field used to display the total in group footer. For some reason it was doubling the calculation.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

shared numberVar sumNetPayable;
numberVar result:= sumNetPayable;
sumNetPayable :=0;

result
```